# Filter pandas dataframe that has arrays in cells

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column `'htgt'` this column consists of array with numbers inside. The size of the array is not constant.  An example of the data:

```
11                  [16, 69]
12                  [61, 79]
13                  [10, 69]
14                      [81]
15          [12, 30, 45, 68]
16                  [10, 76]
17                   [9, 39]
18              [67, 69, 77]
```

How can I filter all the rows that has the number 10 for example.

Comment: That the number 10 exists in the array. I want all the rows that have a specific number the array.

Comment: Could you change your example...? the number 10 doesn't appear in any of the arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store type `list` in `pandas` columns, it's not efficient, and it will make your data harder to interact with.  Just expand your lists to columns:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.htgt.values.tolist())

    0     1     2     3
0  16  69.0   NaN   NaN
1  61  79.0   NaN   NaN
2  10  69.0   NaN   NaN
3  81   NaN   NaN   NaN
4  12  30.0  45.0  68.0
5  10  76.0   NaN   NaN
6   9  39.0   NaN   NaN
7  67  69.0  77.0   NaN
```

Now you can use efficient `pandas` operations to find rows with `10`:

```
out.loc[out.eq(10).any(1)]
```

```
    0     1   2   3
2  10  69.0 NaN NaN
5  10  76.0 NaN NaN
```

If you *insist* on the result being in `list` form, you can use `stack` and `agg`:

```
out.loc[out.eq(10).any(1)].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

```
2    [10.0, 69.0]
5    [10.0, 76.0]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 8):

You could do this by first creating a boolean index using list comprehension:

```
mask = [(10 in x) for x in df['htgt']]
df[mask]
```

Or one line if you prefer:

```
df.loc[[(10 in x) for x in df['htgt']]]
```

[output]

```
htgt
13  [10, 69]
16  [10, 76]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(list):
    return '10' in list

df[df['B'].astype(list).apply(check)]
```

Output:

```
    A   B
2   13  [10, 69]
5   16  [10, 76]
```